# Getting Access Denied error in IE 11 when Object.getOwnPropertyNames()

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

Im getting  Access Denied error  in IE 11 when Object.getOwnPropertyNames(). It seems its due to iframe. The JS code is trying to access parent window's properties which doesn't belong to same orgin.

Though the iframe response has `Allow-cross-origin-policy` as * Im getting this error. I believe because of this header the response content may be rendered properly, But it can't access the parent window properties. Is it true?